# How Can I draw this Hidden Markov Model Figure in Latex?

Tags: graphics

[image]

The tables can be ignored. Also I would prefer if the nodes were more round but its not a big issue.

Comment: What you try so far? With  use of the `tikz-cd` package this should be simple :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a possible way implementing relative positioning.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{positioning}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={circle, draw, thick, align=center, minimum width=1.5cm}]
        \coordinate (BEGIN);
        \coordinate[right=of BEGIN] (1STRAIN);
            \node[anchor=west] (1STRAIN_n) at (1STRAIN) {Rain$_{t-1}$};
        \coordinate[below=of 1STRAIN_n] (1STUNMBRELLA);
            \node[anchor=north] (1STUNMBRELLA_n) at (1STUNMBRELLA) {Umbrella$_{t-1}$};
        \coordinate[right=of 1STRAIN_n] (2NDRAIN);
            \node[anchor=west] (2NDRAIN_n) at (2NDRAIN) {Rain$_{t}$};
        \coordinate[below=of 2NDRAIN_n] (2NDUNMBRELLA);
            \node[anchor=north] (2NDUNMBRELLA_n) at (2NDUNMBRELLA) {Umbrella$_{t}$};
        \draw[-Latex] (BEGIN) -- (1STRAIN);
        \draw[-Latex] (1STRAIN_n) -- (1STUNMBRELLA);
        \draw[-Latex] (1STRAIN_n) -- (2NDRAIN_n);
        \draw[-Latex] (2NDRAIN_n) -- (2NDUNMBRELLA);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Commenting the code you see every object position is placed relatively to the first coordinate `\coordinate (BEGIN);` (namely a relative zero of the drawing), and so on. Node identifier (those with the `_n` subscript, as `(1STRAIN_n)`) serve to the purpose of drawing from the edge instead that from the center.
Doing so you can reiterate and obtain how many circles you want.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in my comment: with `tikz-cd` is simple to draw your hidden Markov model:

```
\documentclass[margin=3.1415692mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, 
                shapes.geometric}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document} 
    \begin{tikzcd}[sep=large,
                   cells={nodes={ellipse, draw, inner xsep=0pt}},
                   every arrow/.append style = {-Stealth, semithick}
                   ]
|[draw=none]|  \vphantom{R_1}\ar[r]
    &   \text{Rain}_{t-1} \ar[r]\ar[d]
        &   \text{Rain}_{t} \ar[r]\ar[d]
            &   \text{Rain}_{t+1}\ar[r]\ar[d]
                & |[draw=none]|  \vphantom{R_1}    \\
     &   \text{Umbrella}_{t-1}  \ar[r]
        &   \text{Umbrella}_{t} \ar[r]
            &   \text{Umbrella}_{t+1}
                &
    \end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A way to make this diagram with a `psmatrix`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pst-node, multido}

\begin{document}

 \[ \def\pscolhooki{\psset{mnode=p}}\def\pscolhookv{\psset{mnode=p}}
 \begin{psmatrix}[mnode=circle, rowsep=1cm, colsep=1.2cm, framesep=1pt]
 & \text{Rain}_{t-1} & \text{\enspace Rain}_{t}\enspace & \text{Rain}_{t+1} &\\
  & \text{Umbrella}_{t-1} & \text{\enspace Umbrella}_{t}\enspace & \text{Umbrella}_{t+1}
    \end{psmatrix}
\psset{arrows=->,arrowinset=0.15, arrowsize=4pt}
\ncline{1,1}{1,2}\ncline{1,4}{1,5}%\ncline{1,4}{2,4}
\multido{\il=2+1, \ir=3+1}{3}{\ncline{1,\il}{1,\ir} \ncline{2,\il}{2,\ir} \ncline{1,\il}{2,\il}}
     \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[on grid,node distance=1.5cm and 2.5cm,>=stealth',thick]
  % \Ellipse[options]{name}{label}
  \newcommand\Ellipse[3][]{\node[draw,rounded corners,inner sep=2pt,#1](#2){#3};}
  % \R[options]{index} defines node Rain_index
  \newcommand\R[2][]{\Ellipse[#1]{R #2}{$\mathit{Rain}_{#2}$}}
  % \U[options]{index} defines node Umbrella_index
  \newcommand\U[2][]{\Ellipse[#1]{U #2}{$\mathit{Umbrella}_{#2}$}}
  
  \R{t-1}                 \R[right=of R t-1]{t} \R[right=of R t]{t+1}
  \U[below=of R t-1]{t-1} \U[right=of U t-1]{t} \U[right=of U t]{t+1}
  
  \draw[->] (R t-1) edge (U t-1) edge (R t)
            (R t)   edge (U t)   edge (R t+1)
            (R t+1) edge (U t+1) edge +(1.5,0);
  \draw[<-] (R t-1) edge +(-1.5,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows,shapes}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[on grid,node distance=1.5cm and 3cm,>=stealth',thick]
  % \Ellipse[options]{name}{label}
  \newcommand\Ellipse[3][]{\node[draw,ellipse,inner sep=0pt,#1](#2){\strut#3};}
  % \R[options]{index} defines node Rain_index
  \newcommand\R[2][]{\Ellipse[#1]{R #2}{$\mathit{Rain}_{#2}$}}
  % \U[options]{index} defines node Umbrella_index
  \newcommand\U[2][]{\Ellipse[#1]{U #2}{$\mathit{Umbrella}_{#2}$}}
  
  \R{t-1}                 \R[right=of R t-1]{t} \R[right=of R t]{t+1}
  \U[below=of R t-1]{t-1} \U[right=of U t-1]{t} \U[right=of U t]{t+1}
  
  \draw[->] (R t-1) edge (U t-1) edge (R t)
            (R t)   edge (U t)   edge (R t+1)
            (R t+1) edge (U t+1) edge +(1.5,0);
  \draw[<-] (R t-1) edge +(-1.5,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```